# Form won't post text input with file upload to SQL table with PHP

Tags: php, sql, forms, post, input

I want to get this image uploading script right, but for whatever reason it doesn't like the description input. It was working perfectly before I added the description input and I can't think of what might be wrong because it looks fine. **My code doesn't like the description input in the form, what is wrong?** Thanks for the help!

HTML Form

```
<h1>Image Gallery</h1>  
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 Description: <textarea maxlength="255" name="description" id="description"></textarea><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

PHP Code (There is code before this but it doesn't matter)

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['UserID']);  
$imageid = mysql_real_escape_string($i);  
$image = mysql_real_escape_string($rename); 
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']); 
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO imageupload (UserID, ImageID, Image, Description) VALUES('".$userid."', '".$imageid."', '".$image."', '".$description."')");  
 if($registerquery) {  
  header( 'Location: manage.php' ) ;
 }  
 else {  
  echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
  echo "<p>Sorry, an error occured. Please go back and try again.</p>";  
 }
```

Comment: where are you processing the image???

Comment: Before the PHP code I entered, but that's all working fine. It's the description input that has a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What datatype is the column for description?

Replace your current query with:

```
$description = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['description']))); 
$register = "INSERT INTO imageupload (UserID, ImageID, Image, Description) VALUES('$userid', '$imageid', '$image', '$description')";

$registerquery = mysql_query($register) or die (mysql_error()); 


 if($registerquery) {  
  header( 'Location: manage.php' ) ;
 }  

 else {  
  echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
  echo "<p>Sorry, an error occured. Please go back and try again.</p>";  
 }
```

Comment: Well, the error told me what my problem was and I fixed it. Apparently I accidentally used the wrong value as the unique key on the table so it wouldn't post... Ugh... Well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the description you insert contains strange characters for db like ";' and so on...?

In case escape the description you get from post with your database php library escaping function... This is also a good practice to avoid sql injection

If you use mysql: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 $description = $_POST['description'];
```

with

```
 $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
```

Comment: I tried that earlier thinking that was the problem, but adding it didn't make it work. I'll add it again though.

Comment: Ahh.  In that case I would recommend following the directions given by @AviateX14, and let us know what the error states if it is still not working.  I might also suggest that you do a DESCRIBE TABLE query on the table you are working with to find out what datatype the description field is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Print out the query and try run it on the mysql command line interface, does it give an error?

you're not cleaning the description string so open to injection there too.